# Does an equation of this type have complex solutions?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, quadratics

How can I show, that every quadratic equation of the type $z^2+az+b=0$ with complex coefficients $a,b$ has a solution in $\mathbb{C}$? And how can I get these solutions?

At first, I tried applying the p-q Formula, but it turned out to be wrong. There must be an other method.

Comment: Try Vieta Theorem.

Comment: Usual formula, usual proof, but we need to know how to find the square roots of numbers that are not necessarily real.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: I've been told, there is a short proof using completion of the square. Is that true?

Comment: The quadratic formula ought to suffice. You do need to know how to find the square root of a complex number, though.

Comment: Yes, the equation is equivalent to $4z^2+4az+4b=0$,  which can be rewritten as $(2z+a)^2=a^2-4b$, giving $2z+a=\pm\sqrt{a^2-4b}$. And now we almost have $z$, except we must find the square roots of $a^2-4b$.

Comment: The simplest way to  find the square roots of a complex number $w$ is to express the number as $r(\cos\theta+i\sin \theta)$. The square roots are $\pm\sqrt{r}(\cos(\theta/2)+i\sin(\theta/2))$. There are other messier formulas for square root.  There is also a more compact  one, $\pm\sqrt{r}e^{i\theta//2}$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: So, do I have to set $a=r_1(\cos{\phi}+i\sin{\phi})$ and $b=r_2(\cos{\psi}+i\sin{\psi})$ and then solve for $z$?

Comment: @Arthur, completing the square is equivalent to using the quadratic formula, since that is how the quadratic formula is derived.

Comment: @Arthur: Not quite, it is $a^2-4b$ that we want to take the square root of, so it is more efficient to compute $a^2-4b$ in the usual way and then go to the sines/cosines representation. If you want me to work out the details for an example, you can leave me a message and I can do it tomorrow (it is late here).